# Does this mean what I think it means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> And social media is filled with tributes to Harden's signature look. "I'll take 5% credit," Harden says of the rise of hipster beards around the nation. "I don't want too much. Just 5%."

Does this mean he thinks people in the nations are having beards partially because of him?

http://time.com/4672996/james-harden-rule-nba/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're exactly right, this means that "he [agrees] that people nation-wide are growing beards partially because of him."

I would say that the key word is "partially" because as Harden has stated, he wants only five percent of the credit.

I would not say that he "thinks" this, again, because he only presumes to assume five percent of the responsibility.

At most, I would say that he "agrees" with the reporter.

The reason I would not use the word, "think," is because, based on the article, it had not been his intention to start a trend nor is it his intention to maintain the beard for trending purposes.

According to the article, he had started it (and continues it) simply for himself because it has become a "part of his persona."

Meanwhile, I would agree with ParaDice's paraphrasing that he "accepts acknowledgement of his contribution."

Comment: And I know that this answer is not an answer to the question specifically, but I had felt that there had been enough of a relatedness between the OP's phrasing of the question and the actual question itself, ergo my decision to post it as such. Plus, though I'm prone to writing long comments, I feel like this would have been a bit long as a comment :D.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is correct.

"to give credit to somebody for something" = to acknowledge somebody's role in / contribution to an achievement. Best examples: the credits at the end of a movie.

Here you've got the opposite perspective on it: he *takes* credit, i.e. he (modestly) accepts the acknowledgement of his contribution to the spread of beards.

Comment: I would not say that he is "demanding" credit, per se. If anything, he's trying to be as modest as possible about taking credit by only taking 5% as opposed to the majority of credit or even 100% of the credit, as evidenced by his statement, "I don't want too much."

Comment: True, demanding wasn't the best word to use here. Edit submitted.

Comment: An excellent edit. I've even included it in my answer.